# Insert and update two tables at the same time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm transferring data between two databases.

My old database has a table called `Customers`, and I have a column called `Email` in there.

My new database has a new table called `Account`, that has a relation with the old `Customers` table.

So, I would like to transfer all the customers from the old database, to the new one. Separate the emails from that table, and Insert into a new one. Example:

My old database table called `Customers`:

```
ID, Email, First Name, Last Name
```

My new database table called `Customers`:

```
ID, Account ID, First Name, Last Name
```

My new database table called `Account`:

```
ID, Email, Password
```

I already transferred the `Customers` to my new database, and I inserted all the `Emails` from the customers into the `Account` table.

But now I would like to update the column Account ID from my new `Customers` table, to relate all the customers to their account.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Account (Email)
    SELECT a.EmailAddress
    FROM AdventureWorks_Test.dbo.Customer a
```

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: In what way does the new Customers "has a relation with the old Customers table."? Have you preserved the old id in the new Customers table? How many records in the old Customers table?

Comment: Now that you've separated them, how do you know which email address goes with the new account row? You broke the connection between the tables by importing them separately. How do you connect them back together again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach here is to preserve ids for later mapping.You can use a temporary table for that.

```
CREATE TABLE #MigrationMapper
(   OldId INT,
    NewId INT )
```

Then you can populate this table while inserting the data into the new table. You can make use of `OUTPUT` clause to get Inserted Id's

```
MERGE INTO Account AS T 
USING AdventureWorks_Test.dbo.Customer s
ON t.Id=a.Id+ NULL --To insert all records 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT ( Email)
VALUES ( s.EmailAddress)
OUTPUT s.Id, INSERTED.ID INTO #MigrationMapper(OldId,NewId);
```

So by joining with the temp table now, you know which email address goes with the new customer row

Comment: I'm receiving this error: The multi-part identifier could not be bound, the ID from the customer is not being recognized

Comment: might be aliasing problem can please create a dbfiddle and share the link

Comment: I found the solution. Its not possible to insert the ID in that way: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c1fe0b9c-9305-4cb0-9237-9374ff4fc03e/error-while-using-output-clause-the-multipart-identifier-could-not-be-bound?forum=transactsql

Comment: I'm retreiving the INSERTED.EmailAddress instead of retreiving the ID from the customers table

Comment: @A.BC now i know the error thanks for pointing out . We can use Merge statement for insert so that we can get the customer id's

Comment: Can you explain me how can I do that?